# How can I get an element's title property in JavaScript by element id?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get an element by its id and get the title attribute. Say I had a div like below with a title attribute and an id. I want to get that title by providing the ID of the div.

```
<div id="myId" title="HeresMyTitle">Hello!</div>
```

I want to provide myId for the id and receive back "HeresMyTitle" without the quotes. Is there a way I can easily do this with out much more?

Comment: `$('#myId').attr('title')` do this

Answer (score 10):

With jQuery:

```
var myTitle = $('#myId').attr('title');
```

without jQuery:

```
var myTitle = document.getElementById('myId').getAttribute('title');
```

Answer (score 3):

Javascript:

```
var myTitle = document.getElementById('myId').title
```

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_title.asp

Answer (score 1):

As you have asked to do it in js, you can use getAttribute("title") to retrieve the title. Follow this snippet:

```html
<div id="myId" title="HeresMyTitle">Hello!</div>

<script>
  
  var divId = document.getElementById("myId");
  
  alert(divId.getAttribute("title"));
  
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myId').attr('title')
```

use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

> Get the value of an attribute for the first element in the set of matched elements.

```js
alert($('#myId').attr('title'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="myId" title="HeresMyTitle">Hello!</div>
```